# Custom control does not allow to focus its children in design view

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, contentcontrol, xaml-designer

I struggle for a while with no luck. My custom control is based on ContentControl, and similar to HeaderedContentControl, just with footer too.

If element in header of original HeaderedContentControl is clicked in design view, in example:

```
    <HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
            <Button Content="header"/>
        </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
        <Button>Content</Button>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
```

Clicking on "header" button will centre xaml code on `<Button Content="header"/>`.

My control:

```
public class TestControl : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof (object), typeof (TestControl), (PropertyMetadata) new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object) null));

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Content")]
    public object Header
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and styling (taken from HeaderedContentControl:

```
<Style>
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cbr:TestControl}">
              <StackPanel>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding cbr:TestControl.Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" />
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" />
              </StackPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

if "header" button is clicked (in design view) in my control, xaml centres on 
`<cbr:TestControl>` instead of `<Button Content="header"/>`

```
    <cbr:TestControl>
        <cbr:TestControl.Header>
            <Button Content="header"/>
        </cbr:TestControl.Header>            
        <Button>Content</Button>            
    </cbr:TestControl>
```